# Blackberry AES encryption error

Tags: blackberry, encryption, java-me, aes

I have implemented AES encryption in BlackBerry using code from the Knowledge Base Article ["How to - Use Advanced Encryption"](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800779/How_to_-_Use_Advanced_Encryption.html?nodeid=800439&vernum=0)

I keep getting error:

> Module 'net_rim_crypto' not found.

In the code I have imported net.rim.device.api.crypto.*; package, but I can't find the package net.rim.crypto.

Do I need to add any external jar for that?

Answer (score 1):

You should install JRE 4.6 and set the API level to 4.6 and OS of the target device should be higher than JRE version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problem with BlackBerry API or OS version, you may consider to use [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) for j2me.