# AES Encryption Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, aes

I am basically and android Developer and as per project requirement i need to develop in blackberry. My task is AES encryption of simple text like HELLO.

**What i did:**
I used this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843783/aes-encryption-with-nopadding-in-blackberry) but as a result i am getting java.lang error in **simulator**

**What i want:**
Kindly Suggest me a way to avoid this error. and sample for AES encryption working sample in Blackberry;

My approach is following:

```
 String mystr = "HELLO";
try
    {
        String str = AES.AESEncryption(mystr.getBytes());
        System.out.print(str);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Please include your error in the question!

Comment: @Duncan  java.lang error is the error

Comment: Are you sure there's no exception message? Can you add the whole stack trace to your question?

Comment: @Duncan  No i cant , as i dont know how to get stack for BB..
this is the main error that i am facing. If you can help me with this plz